# Can I change the default launch activity for an app

Tags: android

I am making changes to an app which necessitate changing the default launch activity away from the old default to a new one which is becoming a landing page for my app. Basically I'm just updating the manifest.xml to add the new activity and move the intent filter over from the old one:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".NewActivity" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".OldActivity" >
    <!-- Launcher used to be here -->
</activity>
```

Does anyone know if this can cause problems for users who are upgrading from an older version of the app? For example if they have a shortcut to the app, does it still work. Additionally do any of the standard app stores such as Google Marketplace (Play Store) / Amazon etc. have any requirements which mean I can't do this?

I suppose the workaround if the activity must remain the same is I can hack the classes so the old activity points to the new class but if I'm worrying over nothing then I prefer to do it cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Well basically when you build your application, all the xml that were changed are compiled into binary and are deployed on the device. So if you change the AndroidManifest.xml, when you build and deploy to device (in the development state), the application from devices is updated, and the new manifest is used. 
So if you change your application's manifest.xml and build an update for the market, it should work the same, I mean by updating the user application and changing the default activity, because the new manifest binary will be loaded.

Good luck,
Arkde

Comment: I realise that but I'm wondering if there are any restrictions on deployment which say the same activity which was specified in the first place must be used thereafter. If there are problems with changing the activity such as to shortcuts then it might mean I have to leave the activty as is and hack around it under the covers.